# How to add a loading image to this Ajax script

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this script I got from internet, which works fine for me. I want to add a loading image which comes up once the field is changed, and goes off once the data has been retrieved from the PHP page.

The problem is that the image doesn't stay (It comes and go before the data has been retrieved). Below is my HTML page

```xml
<form role="form" method="post"">
                           
                                             <label>Amount</label>
                                             
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Amount" id="buyamt" name="buy">
                                               
    <span id="buymsg"></span>
                <label>EXPECTED Value</label>
 <input placeholder="Values Displays Here." id="buyvalue" readonly="" name="buyvalue">

</form>
```

Below is my script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

var pix='<img src="ajax-loader(2).gif">';

$("document").ready(function(){

  

$("#buyamt").change(function() {

$('#buymsg').html(pix);

$.post('chk.php',$('#buyamt').serialize(),function(display){

$('#buyvalue').val(display);},'text');

$('#buymsg').hide(pix);

});

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<span id="buymsg">
    <img id="loading-icon" src="ajax-loader(2).gif">
</span>
```

JS:

```
function ajaxWorking() {
    $('#loading-icon').show();
}

function ajaxDone() {
    $('#loading-icon').hide();
}

$(document).ajaxStart(ajaxWorking);
$(document).ajaxStop(ajaxDone);
```

The ajaxStart/ajaxStop are events meant exactly for this in JQuery. Hope it gets the job done.

Answer (score -1):

Show loading... before post, then hide it after the data is returned.

```js
$('#buymsg').html(pix);
$("#loading").fadeIn(); //show before
$.post('chk.php',$('#buyamt').serialize(),function(display){    
  $('#buyvalue').val(display);
  $("#loading").fadeOut('fast'); //hide after
},'text');

$('#buymsg').hide(pix);
```

```xml
<div id="loading" style="display:none;width:69px;height:89px;border:1px solid black;position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;padding:2px;">
 <img src='loading.gif' width="64" height="64" /><br>Loading..
</div>
```

Comment: This worked with the help of your code.. But the loader dissapears before the result is ready. i expected the loader to keep spinning if the page is not found, but it does not.. Pls     <script type="text/javascript">
$('#buyamt').change(function () {
    // add loading image to div
    $('#buymsg').fadeIn();
    
    // run ajax request
$.post('buycalc.php',$('#buyamt').serialize(),function(display){
            // replace div's content with returned data
   
   $('#buyvalue').val(display);},'text');
            $('#buymsg').fadeOut(4000);
        
    
});

</script>